# Exception Handling: Local Variables

Tags: c#-4.0

In the following code integers `n1` and `n2` can be accessible inside the `try` block.

However they are not recognized by `catch` and `finally` block. May I know the reason?! There is ERROR if I try to print `n1` and `n2` values in `catch` block and `finally` block.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n1, n2;
    try
    {
        n1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        n2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int result;
        result = n1 / n2;
        Console.WriteLine("Result  " + result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error, please provide non zero value for denominator");
        Console.WriteLine("n1 = {0} and n2 = {1}", n1, n2); -> why n1, n2 are unassigned local variables here. 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("n1 = {0} and n2 = {1}", n1, n2); -> why n1, n2 are unassigned local variables here. 
    }
}
```

Comment: The whitespace is strong with this one.

Comment: Initialize n1 and n2 to zero.

Answer (score 0):

> However they are not recognized by catch and finally block. May I know the reason?!

Sure - they're not *definitely assigned*. Imagine `Console.ReadLine` throws an exception. You catch that exception - but you haven't assigned a value to `n1` or `n2`.

You might want to provide initial values for them where you declare them - that way they'd always be definitely assigned. But it's not really clear what you want to happen or why you're trying to use them in the `finally` block anyway. If you really want to access them *after* the `finally` block, you could just return or rethrow the exception within the `catch` block - that way, the only way of getting to after the `finally` block would be via code that assigns values to `n1` and `n2`, so they'd be definitely assigned and you could read from them.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler complains that they *might* be unassigned because you only assign to the variables inside the `try` block and as far as it is concerned there's no guarantee that the caught exception won't be thrown *before* the assignment.

Try initializing them to zero:

```
int n1 = 0;
int n2 = 0;
```